# How to exclude composer autoloader files from phpunit coverage report (using netbeans/windows)

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

[image]

My 'test project' contains only the Application.php and the ApplicationTest.php but the phpunit collect the coverage information about composer autoloader files also, which is wrong. How can I exclude the autoloader files from the coverage report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the configuration for code coverage, you'll almost always set the 'whitelist' in the phpunit.xml file to only cover your main source files - this also speeds up the test-run, as it's not having to also run code-coverage of all the library files in the vendor/ directory (because that can take a **long** time).

```
<filter>
  <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true"
             addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
    <!-- only collect code coverage in src/**/*.php files -->
    <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    <exclude>
       <!-- directories/files to not cover (within src/) -->
       <directory suffix=".php">./src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
       <directory suffix=".php">./src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
       <directory suffix=".php">./src/tests/</directory>
    </exclude>
  </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Configure a whitelist and do not add the autoloader to it.